# Why lighttpd cannot access fastCGI Unix socket?

Tags: lighttpd, fastcgi

I have an C application which opens fastCGI Unix socket via fcgi library on Ubuntu 22.

I'm trying to connect to it from lighttpd and get Permission denied error even when I chmod the socket to 777.

What could cause the error?

```
root@vxu22:/etc/lighttpd/conf-enabled# cat 10-fastcgi.conf
server.modules += ( "mod_fastcgi" )
fastcgi.server += ( ".php" =>
    ((
        "socket" => "/home/user/full/path/fcgi.sock",
        "broken-scriptfilename" => "enable"
    ))
)


root@vxu22:/var/log/lighttpd# cat error.log
2023-05-15 16:00:06: (server.c.1551) server started (lighttpd/1.4.63)
2023-05-15 16:00:14: (gw_backend.c.285) establishing connection failed: socket: unix:/home/user/full/path/fcgi.sock: Permission denied
2023-05-15 16:00:14: (gw_backend.c.995) all handlers for /login? on /login are down.
2023-05-15 16:00:16: (gw_backend.c.362) gw-server re-enabled: unix:/home/user/full/path/fcgi.sock  0 /home/user/full/path/fcgi.sock


root@vxu22:/var/log/lighttpd# ls -l /home/user/full/path/fcgi.sock
srwxrwxrwx 1 user users 0 May 15 15:31 /home/user/full/path/fcgi.sock=
```

Comment: If lighttpd is ultimately (e.g. `User=` in systemd service) run with a non-root user and that user doesn't have necessary permission (e.g. `x`) *along the path* (e.g. `/home/user`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment of Tom Yan is correct - the problem was not the file permissions but rather file location.

After I moved the socket to /var/www/html/ the connection succeeded.